# sending mail from php: 2 received entrys with phpmailer

Tags: php, email, header, phpmailer, email-headers

Hi I tried to send an email over phpmailer. I take phpmailer to send it over smtp.
Every customer have by us have an owne ip. I sent an test email and I see that there was two "received" entrys in the email header. Is it possible to show only one? Because i think if one of our customers sent spam we have a problem with our main server.

The Script:

```
    require('lib/phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php');
    require('lib/phpmailer/class.smtp.php'); // stellt die Methoden für SMTP-Connect bereit
    $mail = new PHPMailer();

    // Anmelden am SMTP-Server
    $mail->IsSMTP();
    $mail->Host     = $smtphostname; 
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true; 
    $mail->Username = $smtpbenutzername;
    $mail->Password = $smtppasswort;
    $mail->Port     = $smtpport;

    $mail->Subject = 'SMTP - Test';
    $mail->IsHTML(true);
    $mail->Body     = 'Dies ist eine SMTP - Testmail. Es ist keine Aktion erforderlich, sondern bestätigt lediglich die Einrichtung eines neuen SMTP - Kontos im Mailsystem.';
    $mail->From     = $absendeadresse;
    $mail->FromName = 'SMTP - Testmailer';
    $mail->AddReplyTo($antwortadresse);
    $mail->Sender     = $bounceadresse;
    $mail->CharSet  =  "utf-8";

    $Xuserid = 500;
    $mail->Xuserid  =  $Xuserid;
    $mail->AddAddress($adminemail);
```

The mail header:

```
Return-Path: bounce@customerdomain.com

Received: from dc.ourdomain.com ([IP.IP.IP.IP]) by mx-ha.web.de (mxweb008)
with ESMTP (Nemesis) id 0M0Ptt-1ULMIH1Vcb-00uXxW for <xxx@gmail.com>; Sun, 19 May 2013 20:50:56 +0200

Received: from [IP.IP.IP.IP] (port=42845 helo=ourdomain.com) by dc.ourdomain.com with esmtpa (Exim 4.80)
(envelope-from <bounce@customerdomain.com>) id 1Ue8h7-00089Y-6b for xxx@gmail.com; Sun, 19 May 2013 20:50:57 +0200

Date: Sun, 19 May 2013 20:50:57 +0200

To: xxx@gmail.com

From: SMTP - Testmailer <info@customerdomain.com>

Reply-To: info@customerdomain.com

Subject: SMTP - Test

Message-ID: <933166e45238090b8be63d3e2891dd6b@ourdomain.com>
```

I don't want to show this... is it possible?

```
Received: from dc.ourdomain.com ([IP.IP.IP.IP]) by mx-ha.web.de (mxweb008)
with ESMTP (Nemesis) id 0M0Ptt-1ULMIH1Vcb-00uXxW for <xxx@gmail.com>; Sun, 19 May 2013 20:50:56 +0200
```

Answer (score 0):

The headers are added by the mail servers that the email passes through. Apparently, your dc (Domain Controller) seems to route the mail traffic through web.de. Thus, you cannot control this unless you send it through different mail servers.

Also, as you seem to be located in Germany: Germany (unlike other countries bordering to it) has a reasonable legal framework protecting internet service providers from malicious acts that their users commit, as long as they apply reasonably due diligence. So at least from a legal perspective, there is no particular problem with these headers.

Comment: hmm... is there no possibility that I can say in cpanel, that our customers has an owne virtual server? Because they all have also their own ip and domain.

Comment: I don't know cPanel. I can just say that this is an infrastructure issue, and it has to do with the route the email takes. Usually though (from what I know about hosting providers around here), they operate a single mail server for all the customers, not individual ones. After all, most customer's mail servers would be doing nothing all day anyways.

Comment: What I can say for sure is that this is nothing that can be influenced from within PHP.